# Escaping braces from MyBatis value - Oracle

Tags: escaping, mybatis, mybatis-mapper

This is the problematic part of my MyBatis mapper:

```
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="xy" 
  open="(" separator="or" close=")">
     contains(t.mycol, '{' || #{item} || '}') > 0 
</foreach>
```

If, for example, the #{item} contains '}', I get:

```
Error code: DRG-50900
Description: text query parser error on line string, column string
Cause: bad query
```

1. How do I properly escape all possibly problematic characters?
2. where to put the logic? In the mapper/dao/service..?

So that for example '}' would become escaped (and if the text already contained escaped '}' to leave it that way).

used in the project:

- Java 8
- Spring
- Oracle database
- MyBatis

Comment: What are the values you are providing in the list `xy`, and what's the expected resulting SQL you want?

Comment: imo the foreach part is irelevant. 
the #{item} might have value of "lorem}", and I want to find out if t.mycol contains the "lorem}", or at least I want it to not throw exceptions when '}' occured in #{item}